# Elasticsearch-oss cannot bind to local and external addresses at same time

Tags: elasticsearch

trying to set Elasticsearch to bind to another address than local, I'm having lot of troubles..

Elasticsearch-oss 7.7 Opendistro.

elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
```

cannot set to any syntax... tryed an array

```
network.host: [ "127.0.0.1", "100.0.0.1" ]
```

...and tryed different variations, like special values, etc.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

also not working...

```
network:
  host: _global_
```

also not working...

(using global address for testing)

```
network:
  host: _local_
```

working

```
network:
  host: _local_ , _interface-name_
```

...not working.

---

Finally I found a way to bind to another address. And I can get a request externally...but now the localhost is failing!

```
network.host: localhost
http.host: 100.0.0.1
```

From the same server:

```
curl -XGET https://localhost:9200 -u admin:admin --insecure
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

From the client:

```
 curl -XGET https://100.0.0.1:9200 -u admin:admin --insecure
{
  "name" : "somename",
  "cluster_name" : "someclustername",
  "cluster_uuid" : "someclusteruuid",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.7.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "81a1e9eda8e6183f5237786246f6dced26a10eaf",
    "build_date" : "2020-05-12T02:01:37.602180Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

waiting your approach to this problem..

Thanks

[edit]

Now I found a certificate error log....I don't know if it is related.
Using default security settings for Opendistro plugin

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:291) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:184) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:167) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:729) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:684) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:475) ~[?:?]
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Hi!  First off, `_global_` Should be the correct value for your `network.host`. A few things I would like to double check with you after that. You say "from the client", and show a working cURL to the `100.0.0.1` IP address. What does "client" mean in this context? 

I am less familiar with this Opendistro package, but it looks like it has turned SSL on by default. Have you generated or signed your own certificates? My understanding is that ES would straight up crash if you don't have certs present.

Comment: Is that the entire contents of your elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: You need to add `discovery.type: single-node` as well

Answer (score 0):

Here the full elasticsearch.yml
The security cert options are default by Opendistro

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: somename
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
network.host: localhost
http.host: 100.0.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true

######## Start OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Configuration ########
# WARNING: revise all the lines below before you go into production
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false
opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled: true
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
opendistro_security.allow_default_init_securityindex: true
opendistro_security.authcz.admin_dn:
  - CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=test, C=de

opendistro_security.audit.type: internal_elasticsearch
opendistro_security.enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
opendistro_security.check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
opendistro_security.restapi.roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"]
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3
######## End OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Demo Configuration ########
```

> What does "client" mean in this context?
> A client-node that is shipping logs to the server-node. In this case for testing purposses.

I will configure the certs properly and the discovery.type to see if that can be the fix

Thanks

Comment: discovery.type: single-node doesn't solve it. Actually I was not able to change the pem certificates... But now running in http only, the client throws this log: [WARN ][c.a.o.s.a.BackendRegistry] [sofistic-control] Authentication finally failed for elastic from <client-ip>